# Can't boot windows or ubuntu!

Tags: grubrescue

I recently dual booted my sony VAIO having pre-installed Windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.04 using a liveCD, and Ubuntu worked fine. (I had done the needful as seen in [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)  and Ubuntu was working perfectly) By the way, I had pre-partitioned my Windows C:drive and during booting I just selected "Install Ubuntu along with Windows 8" and did not ask for any partitioning!. After installation, I even got the option to select windows or ubuntu during startup but windows wouldn't boot on being selected. So I selected 'boot repair' as shown in the link (using recommended settings and all). An option came there to remove grub and reinstall it. Everything went fine and I rebooted only to find:

> GRUB loading
>   error: invalid arch independent ELF magic
>   grub rescue>

on typing ls

I get points like (hdX,gptY). I have found my file lies in (hd0,gpt12) but insmod linux does not work.
On starting with my liveCD, nothing happens, I cannot boot from it and I get the previous screen only. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do now:

1. Go download boot repair disk from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/settings/mirror_choices?projectname=boot-repair-cd&filename=boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso).
2. Put it in USB via [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
   OR you can always burn it to CD.
3. Boot from the newly created media (USB or CD).
4. Go through simple steps like selecting language etc. then 'Boot repair' dialog will appear; select 'Recommended Repair' and re-boot your PC.
5. Now its done.